# Opening emacs in terminal results in Gtk-WARNING

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, gtk, emacs

This warning is shown when I try to open emacs in terminal:

```
(emacs:5854): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2603:31: Missing name of pseudo-class
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

A search online yields [this issue with the paper theme](https://github.com/snwh/paper-gtk-theme/issues/245) and [this issue with the numix theme.](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-gtk-theme/issues/167)

Apparently it is caused by your icon theme no longer fully supporting the current version of GTK that you are using. The developers of both themes replied that updating GTK or using an older version of the theme will fix the issue.

However, it seems that this shouldn't cause any problems and can be ignored without consequences.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)